# Angular 6 App stuck on loading on localhost

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript

I have following app on stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/ang-rafzby
that works fine in their web environment, but when I download the project and try to run it on my machine, it gets stuck on 'loading'.

I've installed all required npm modules, even the peer ones and just can't find the solution for this.

Edit(chrome console output):

```
    ERROR Error: The selector "app-root" did not match any elements
at DefaultDomRenderer2.push../node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/fesm5/platform-browser.js.DefaultDomRenderer2.selectRootElement (platform-browser.js:1068)
at BaseAnimationRenderer.push../node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/fesm5/animations.js.BaseAnimationRenderer.selectRootElement (animations.js:228)
at DebugRenderer2.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.DebugRenderer2.selectRootElement (core.js:11449)
at createElement (core.js:8129)
at createViewNodes (core.js:10360)
at createRootView (core.js:10313)
at callWithDebugContext (core.js:11344)
at Object.debugCreateRootView [as createRootView] (core.js:10831)
at ComponentFactory_.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ComponentFactory_.create (core.js:8659)
at ComponentFactoryBoundToModule.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ComponentFactoryBoundToModule.create (core.js:3311)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution!
in the index.html the app-root selector has to be inside the html 'body' tag like this:

```
    <body>
     <app-root></app-root>
    </body>
```

and stackblizt doesn't need that or just does it by itself.

Comment: That's exactly right. On StackBlits, like CodePen, JsFiddle and others, the HTML editor only shows what goes inside the `<body>` tags. You can confirm this by looking in the Chrome Development tools.